# Geodesic distance between two points

Tags: c

Is there a library in C that can calculate the geodesic distance between two points?

Comment: First result on google: http://grass.osgeo.org/programming6/geodist_8c.html

Comment: what kind of accuracy do you require over what kind of distances?

Comment: centimeters could be excellent!

Comment: here some simple examples, https://github.com/cucurbita/geodesy/blob/master/Source/GeodesyDistance.c other : -- the NASA has a geodesic lib too
-- http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not necessary to compute geodesic distances up to centimeter accuracy as you'd have to model local geography to the same scale.

There are two cases I can think of where such accuracy might be desired:

- you're actually interested in the straight-line distance and know exact coordinates, including height above sea level
- you're working with a toy model and are interested in general properties, not practical applicability

In the first case, I'd transform from geographical coordinates `(φ,λ,h)` to geocentric cylindrical coordinates `(r,z,λ)`

```
r = (a²/k + h)·cosφ
z = (b²/k + h)·sinφ
λ = λ
```

where

```
k = √(a²·cos²φ + b²·sin²φ)
```

In the second case, I'd use [Vincenty's formulae](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html).

You can find (hopefully correct) C implementations of both algorithms under [my bitbucket account](https://bitbucket.org/cggaertner/geo/src).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've ported the geodesic routines in GeographicLib to C.  See
http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/C/index.html